# When will $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ strictly contain $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $F$ be a field, $p(x)\in F[x]$ with $\deg p(x)\geq 1$. I know that when viewing $F$ as its isomorphic copy in $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$, then $F\subseteq F/\langle p(x)\rangle$.

However, when will $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ strictly contain $F$, i.e., $F\subsetneq F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ (ps: view $F$ as its isomorphic copy in $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$)? I have been headache about these materials in the early steps, so I think I should ask for the help.

What I have tried is that: I know there's a theorem that $p(x)$ is reducible over $F$ iff $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is a field. So when $p(x)$ is reducible, then $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ is not a field, then $F\subsetneq F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ in this case. Am I correct? And how if $p(x)$ is reducible?

Comment: I believe in general $F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ is a vector space over $F$ of dimension $\deg p$, so you need the degree of $p$ to be $1$.

Comment: Well I hope the upvotes I got above figured out I said the opposite of what I meant. The degree of $p$ must be strictly greater than $1$ if $F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ strictly contains $F$ (and must be $1$ if we want $F[X]/\langle p(x) \rangle \cong F$).

Comment: @TobErnack How about the sufficient condition for $F[x]/\langle p(x) \rangle$ strictly contains F?

Answer (score 2):

$F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle$ is an $F$-vector space; your question boils down to asking whether the dimension of this vector space is strictly greater than one.

It's not too hard to show that $\dim\left( F[x] / \langle p(x) \rangle \right) = \deg(p)$; e.g. by writing down a basis.

Comment: But this will require also that $p$ is irreducible?

Comment: @user284331 no. It's always of dimension $n$, irreducibility of $p$ only matters for whether or not $F[x]/(p)$ is a field or not.

Answer (score 0):

There is always an injective map $F \mapsto F[x]/(p(x))$, unless $(p(x))$ is the unit ideal.

To see this, suppose $p(x)$ is not a unit. Then $F[x]/(p(x)) \neq 0$, so the composition $F \to F[x] \to F[x]/(p(x))$ is nonzero (it sends $1$ to $1 \neq 0$). But the kernel of this map is an ideal of $F$, which means it's $(0)$. In other words, the map is injective.

$\textbf{EDIT}$: If we want this map to only be injective, we have to require that $deg(p(x)) > 1$

Comment: @Hurkyl Right. I missed the strictly part

Comment: So the conclusion is that "if $p(x)$ is irreducible and $\deg p(x)\geq 2$, then $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ strictly contains $F$"? And by the way, is my observation in the last paragraph of the post correct?

Comment: @Eric There's no need for $p(x)$ to be irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you gave an integral domain (or in your case a field) $F$ and an ireducible polynomial $p(x)$ then $F[x]/<p(x)>\cong A$ where $A$ is a field. The elemet of $A$ are the equivalence classes of the division remainders with $p(x)$. So in $A$ $[a(x)]=[r(x)]$ where $a(x)=b(x)p(x)+r(x)$.This means that if whatever we do, if we $\deg(p(x))\geq2$ then $A$ will contain $F$ as long with other elements (say for example the class $[x+p]$).

Now if $\deg(p(x))\leq1$ then $A$ will contain *at best* $F$ (depending if $p(x)$ is irreducible or not) so we conclude that for $A$ to be contain $F$ $\deg(p(x))\geq 2$

Comment: So the conclusion is that "if $p(x)$ is irreducible and $\deg p(x)\geq 2$, then $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ strictly contains $F$"?

Comment: anther question, how did you infer "*So for $A$ to contain $F$ then $p(x)$ must be irreducible*"? I got lost here.

Comment: Hmm, you are right, It doesn't seem true. I have in mind that since we wanted $A$ to contain $F$ we would like $A$ to be a field which is obviously wrong. No that I thing of it we dont care of irreducibility, so only the degree beinge bigger than $1$ will suffice. I will edit my post.